# cassandra order by non-primary key workaround

Tags: sorting, cassandra, key

**Cassandra database**

It seems that there is no way to order on anything but primary keys.

I have two columns: ID and timestamp.

I only want ONE(!) row per ID, but I want to filter (basically same as sort?) my results based on timestamp.

I want to run this command:

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM " + TableName + " WHERE timestamp < ? ALLOW FILTERING;
```

How can I do this while making sure I have only a single row per id (which is not possible if my primary key consists of both (ID and timestamp)

Comment: Why would you *want* to use `ALLOW FILTERING`?  `ALLOW FILTERING` basically tells Cassandra "Hey, I don't care how much performance sucks, just let me query like I'm in a relational database."

Comment: Take a look at this link, it should suffice for your purposes: https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

Comment: @Aaron I tried to remove it at some point and got an error saying that I couldn't sort without it. My query didnt run. Also performance doesn't really matter for the programs that use that (nightly jobs and the like).

Comment: @LucasFranceschi I can't see which of those could be a solution, sorry. All of them seem to save each additional timestamp instead of overwriting the "latest". I want 1 timestamp for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to thoroughly test this method. But I think that I've found a workaround.

I will allow timestamp to be part of the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TableName + " ( key blob, timestamp bigint, PRIMARY KEY( key, timestamp )
```

But before calling UPDATE/PUT I will delete all rows

```
WHERE id = ?
```

Such that it will replace the current timestamp for that ID. In that way I should still be able to sort on timestamp, while preserving one row per ID.